# Light in additive loaded scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

Our game is a multiplayer VR game.We have a in game lobby were you select weapons etc and then spawn into the match. The in game lobby gets loaded into the main scene using LoadLevelAdditive.

We disable the mixed mode directional light when you spawn in the lobby and enable it when spawning in match.

Problem is the addtive scene look way different when loaded into the main scene, here are two screens

On its own in editor, here it look as I intended
[image]

When loaded additive at runtime
[image]

Whats going on here?

Comment: it would be better if you expanded the scene items in heirarchy before screenshot :-)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a light source giving extra lighting to your scene. Check the additive scene for light sources. Check if some gameObject has a light source attached to it (maybe the camera). Note that there's a directional light that's added by default to new scenes.

Also check that this little button is disabled *(or enabled if you want)*:

[image: Camera light button]

Comment: It seems Unity  is broken in this regard, google "unity additive lightmap" or "unity additive light probes"